# socket.io swift not working on real device

Tags: ios, swift, socket.io

I'm using this [project](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client-swift)
I have a `node.js` server, and implemented an ios client.

It's working great on the simulator but when i'm running it on a real device i cannot make a connection.

It seems that that connection request doesn't go out of the iphone because i cannot see any movement on the server side(run on debug mode).

Also, the server is not sitting on the localhost so i cannot see why is it working well on the simulator but not on a real device.. what do i miss?

The log from `XCode`:

```
2015-12-30 11:13:53.579 socket4[560:1722668] Log SocketIOClient: Adding handler for event: important message
2015-12-30 11:13:53.581 socket4[560:1722668] Log SocketIOClient: Adding handler for event: connect
2015-12-30 11:13:53.581 socket4[560:1722668] Log SocketIOClient: Adding handler for event: error
2015-12-30 11:13:53.582 socket4[560:1722668] Log SocketIOClient: Adding engine
2015-12-30 11:13:53.582 socket4[560:1722668] Log SocketEngine: Starting engine
2015-12-30 11:13:53.582 socket4[560:1722668] Log SocketEngine: Handshaking
2015-12-30 11:15:08.713 socket4[560:1723014] ERROR SocketIOClient: The operation couldn’t be completed. Operation timed out
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used port 3000.
Turns out that for some reason that very port is blocked on the real device and not on the simulator.
It might be because Apple itself uses that port for its purposes.

I just changed the port on the server and on the client app and voilà, it works!

Answer (score 0):

In iOS (Xcode), it worked after setting the minimum deployment target on Pod to iOS 12+ because NWProtocolTCP is implemented for iOS 12+.

You need change the minimum deployment target for the Starscream pod which comes with Socket.io.